# How to install ubuntu on a sd card

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 15.04, sd-card

I made a bootable usb and booted from it, then i installed ubuntu but not on the hard drive, but on the SD Card, when installation was done i shut down and went to the bios to start from the SD Card, but there was no option. I have a Acer Aspire ES1-111

Comment: If the BIOS does not support booting from SD card you should ask to Acer to provide a BIOS update that contemplates the possibility. It is not something that an operating system can solve, it's a manufacturer choice.

Comment: An internal SD is not a bootable device.  The only way to boot from an SD is through a USB cable connected to a card reader (that would make it a "boot from USB" since the BIOS does not see what is at the other end). You can use an SD for a /home/ but the system itself would still needs to be on a bootable medium.

Answer (score 0):

I a recent blog post I read an article about booting Linux on an Acer Aspire One indirectly from the SD card via a boot loader on a Pen Drive. Maybe this could provide a solution for you.

http://www.barryhubbard.com/linux/booting-acer-aspire-one-from-sd-card/

Having heard about the issue with booting an Acer Aspire One from the SD card and having read myself a note on Acers website that it's not supported and not possible I was surprised to read a comment to a blog post mentioned above where someone claimed that it was possible on his Acer aspire E11 ES1-111M-C7DE.

It seems that some newer BIOS's support direct boot from an SD card.